# Lucene RAMDirectory deprecated - how to keep Directory RAM-only anyway?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm currently using the class `org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory` for a fast RAM-based index without the requirement of hard disk write permissions. RAM size & persistence is not a limiting factor. However, `RAMDirectory` is marked as deprecated and also seems to be problematic for large indexes according to its [API](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html).

So my question is, what is a ***RAM-only*** alternative for the deprecated `RAMDirectory`?

Anything writing on hard disk is out of the question for me (read only) & also seems to be quite a bit slower on my own systems. I was thinking about using `FSDDirectory` with a RAMDisk but couldn't find a way to create said RAMDisk using java / the jar only (again requires changing the system).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[ByteBuffersDirectory](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/main/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/store/ByteBuffersDirectory.java) is the replacement for `RAMDirectory`.

The chart below makes it crystal clear why `RAMDiretory` was depreciated and then removed. BBDIR is `ByteBuffersDirectory` and RAMDIR is `RAMDirectory`.

[image]
Chart by Dawid Weiss. Source: [LUCENE-8438](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8438?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16571426#comment-16571426) and shown under Apache 2.0 License.

Comment: I'm wasn't arguing for RAMDirectory, quite the opposite i was looking for a replacement and unable to find one without disk write access.  So thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could also just create a [ramdisk](https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/943-create-a-ram-disk-in-linux%20ramdisk)

Comment: If you have a way to create a ramdisk from within the java program i run, i'm all ears. If its about creating a ramdisk with extra installations and system access, i already mentioned specifically thats not an option.

Comment: Oh. I was too quick. But there seems to be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428217/can-a-java-ram-disk-be-created-to-be-used-with-the-java-io-api

Comment: Thank you, the link is very helpful - seems like there is no way (as in, no way without very extensive own additions) for a java-only ramdisk.